# Updating Bibtex references on Texmaker

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

Each time that I add an additional source to my *.bib file, I have to close my *.tex file, re-open it and then press F11, to have that file available as a list of references to cite from. Is this necessary to do each time?

Thanks,
CS

Comment: you are describing an interaction with some editor, but have not said which editor it is (neither tex not bibtex have any interaction modes related to keys like F11)

Comment: I am using Texmaker

Comment: OK I added that to the tags, you may also want to edit the question to ask about texmaker so texmaker users see it. I have never used that editor so can not help, sorry.